# Retrieve a Drupal View's result set

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, module, view, drupal-views

I'm trying to find out how to retrieve a Views result set.

I have a search content type that I use to control API searches to an API service. I need to periodically retrieve this list of searches and perform the API calls.

How can I get the View's result set in or to perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [views_get_result_view()](http://www.pridedesign.ie/content/drupal-get-view-results-php-code).